# Join on first column of two files

Tags: linux, unix, join, awk

How can I join two files by the first column of each?

file1:

```
116
116
116
116
116
117
117
117
117
117
```

file2:

```
1   37.8378378378378
2   30.5009605438156
3   35.4106079490375
4   25.6565656565657
.....
.....
116 49.4073275862069
117 25.8182578688696
118 36.1389759665622
119 36.7218282111899
120 55.1587301587302
```

I want to match the 1st columns in both files and print like this:

```
116  49.4073275862069
116  49.4073275862069  
116  49.4073275862069 
116  49.4073275862069 
116  49.4073275862069 
117  25.8182578688696
117  25.8182578688696
117  25.8182578688696
117  25.8182578688696
117  25.8182578688696
```

Comment: $ join file? # files must be sorted first, so $ sort -o file2 file2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one-liner:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}$1 in a{print $1,a[$1]}' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this simply with `join`

```
join <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: how would you specify on which columns to do this?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов using `-j` for the same field in both files of `-1` and `-2`. Read `man join`.

Comment: I think you need to be careful when sorting things for join, you need to make sure the sort is done on the first column http://superuser.com/questions/33362/how-to-unix-sort-by-one-column-only