# Insert a new column in one text file and match the pattern from another file

Tags: linux, command-line

I have two text files. I want to insert a new column in `file1` where the new column contains the corresponding clone name of that particular barcode. Does anyone know how? I know how to insert but I don't know how to match the pattern. I am looking for a linux command. Thank you!

`file1`:

```
BAR_001
BAR_001
BAR_002
BAR_002
BAR_003
BAR_003
BAR_003
...
BAR_400
BAR_400
```

`file2`:

```
BAR_001 Clone1
BAR_002 Clone2
BAR_003 Clone3
BAR_004 Clone4
BAR_005 Clone5
...
BAR_400 Clone400
```

My desired outcome is:

```
BAR_001 Clone1
BAR_001 Clone1
BAR_002 Clone2
BAR_002 Clone2
BAR_003 Clone3
BAR_003 Clone3
BAR_003 Clone3
...
BAR_400 Clone400
BAR_400 Clone400
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Since your input seems to be sorted, `join file1 file2` would be enough. I'm pretty sure there's a duplicate with more explanations, let me check...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join on first column of two files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15210503/join-on-first-column-of-two-files)